# How to create a hybrid MPA and SPA with Vue JS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, architecture

I am just getting into web development, and was thinking of using Vue to create a website idea I've had for a while.

I've done some research and think that a hybrid MPA/SPA website would be the best. The goal is to have multiple "pages" (e.g. a dashboard, login/signup, about, help, etc.) Some of these "pages" will need to act as an SPA: for example, the dashboard will need to show a filesystem, various different things, and the login/signup page will need to show multiple things at different times (the pricing, then the form, etc.)

How could I go about this in Vue? I've done some googling, but I can't find a solid answer. Also, feel free to tell me if I'm going about this the wrong way, and if a pure SPA or MPA would be better.

Thanks :)

Comment: https://nuxtjs.org/

Comment: @Ifaruki cool, I just checked this out. How does it allow me to do what I want to do?

Comment: well nuxt is a combination of MPA/SPA it has SSR and feels like an SPA. i would stick to it. for certain pages you can set `ssr: false` so its deactivated. Deploying is a bit harder then a usual MPA because you would need an server that has node..js

Comment: @Ifaruki awesome, thanks! for deploying, I was planning on using Heroku - I'll cross that bridge when I come to it :)

Comment: okey. they have an guide how to do it on heroku https://nuxtjs.org/faq/heroku-deployment nuxt should be good to go. full SEO support

Comment: @Ifaruki do you know if this is better than, say, vue pages?

Comment: what do you mean by vue pages?

Comment: @Ifaruki https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages

Comment: nuxt pages are vue pages. you create pages easelie by creating an file with an `.vue` extension in the pages folder

Comment: @Ifaruki so nuxt and vue pages are the same? Is nuxt an easier way to use vue pages?

Comment: yes. nuxt is build up on vue.js. It simplify things like routing, vuex , SSR and more stuff. for example: In nuxt you need to go to your directory `pages` now add an file to it `/pages/test.vue` and thats it. You added a route by just adding an file to your pages folder. in the browser you can go to `localhost:3000/test` and it will show you the page. The `.vue` file needs to contain atleast an `template` with atleast 1 element in it